# Contact Form 7 add line breaks in multiple checkboxes in email

Tags: wordpress, email, checkbox, contact-form-7

I have a CF7 form where I have multiple checkboxes and the user has to select at least one option. Here is the code I'm using.

`[checkbox* checkbox-380 use_label_element "option1" "option2" "option3"]`

Everything is working. But when the form is submitted the result in the email display the selected checkboxes in one line separated by commas like below:

`option1, option2, option3`.

But I want each item to be displayed in a new line like this:

`option1
option2
option3`

Is it doable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just add is in your custom css:

```
span.wpcf7-list-item {display: block;}
```